# In neo4j on what basis paths from apoc.path.spanningTree will get sorted(default sort)?

Tags: sorting, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I am using apoc.path.spanningTree with some relationship filters and some label filters with maxLevel:-1
as a result, I am getting 5 paths as output in some order. I am not able to understand the basis of its sorting.
What I have noticed is, sorting is taking place on the basis of neo4j id of the last node in the path.
But If I update any intermediate node in any of the paths then this order changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The procedure is not documented to return the paths in any particular order, so you should not assume a particular ordering is used. And the algorithm can change at any time anyway.

If your query needs the paths in a specific order, it should sort the returned paths itself.